# Identifying Lewis acid

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, aqueous-solution, ph

What is the Lewis acid on the reactants side?

$$\ce{HNO2(aq) + HPO4^{2-}(aq) <=> NO2-(aq) + H2PO4-(aq)}$$

The book says it is the $\ce{H+}$ only, not the whole molecule of the nitrous acid, how so?

Comment: That's a Bronsted not Lewis equilibrium.

Comment: @Mithoron the reaction can be interpreted in terms of the Lewis theory.  But yes, when that theory identifies $\ce{H^+}$ as the acid, the Bronsted interpretation is usually simpler.

Comment: Can you plzz tell which book this question is from...?

Comment: the book is called Chemical Principals, The Quest for insight, 7th ed.

Answer (score 3):

What we have, in the Lewis theory, is an acid-base *displacement* reaction.  The Lewis acid, $\ce{H^+}$, is initially combined with one Lewis base, $\ce{NO2^-}$.  Then another Lewis base, $\ce{HPO4^{2-}}$, takes the $\ce{H^+}$ away displacing the $\ce{NO2^-}$.

Similarly when $\ce{HCl}$ is dissolved in water and dissociates, the water is displacing the chloride ion.  The Lewis acid involved in this displacement is again $\ce{H^+}$.